# Weird blank spaces in my PHP/HTML code

Tags: php, html

I have been converting my PHP files from ANSI to UTF-8 and something weird happened to my code and I don't know why. This is my index.php code

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="container">

</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

And my header.php is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Somethingá</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>">
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
    <div id="header-wrap">
        <div id="logo"><a href="index.php"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/logo.png" alt="ODS"></a></div>
        <div id="header-text">Karviná</div>
        <hr>
        <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="righter">something</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="righter">something</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="righter">something</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="righter">something</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="righter">something</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="righter2">something</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the last footer.php contains this:

```
<div id="footer">

</div>
</body>
```

But there is a problem that I can't understand. It's a wordpress theme, all files are in UTF-8 coding. Everytime I open the site with this selected them, there are blank spaces. For example header is not at the top of page but about 20px from the top. I checked the code which I can see in developer console in Google Chrome and it contains this:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css"></style>
</head>
<body>



<title>Somethingá</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://XX.XXX.XXX.XX/wp-content/themes/xxx/style.css">
<div id="header">
    <div id="header-wrap">
        <div id="logo"><a href="index.php"><img src="http://93.185.106.91/wp-content/themes/ods/img/logo.png" alt="ODS"></a></div>
        <div id="header-text">Karviná</div>
        <hr>
        <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="righter">something</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="righter">something</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="righter">something</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="righter">something</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="righter">something</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="righter2">something</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



<div id="footer">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It's totally weird. I don't get it why did content of `<head> </head>` moved to `<body> </body>`. It also generated that huge blank spaces between `<body>` and `<title>`, `</div>` and  `<div id="footer">`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code was clean but if you are creating Wordpress Theme and you need UTF 8. You have to use UTF-8 without BOM! Not with BOM.

Answer (score 0):

firstly, I suggest looking at the "View Source" option to see the actual code that is being loaded into the browser. Looking at the developer tools will show you the code after the browser has processed it, which will be different to the code you're actually outputting.

The reason it's different is because the browser will handle any invalid HTML and try to arrange the page as best it can if the HTML isn't valid.

In your case, it's fairly clear that there's something invalid in the HTML. I can't see what it is, but you can check it for yourself very easily by using the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org). This will tell you of any HTML errors in your code.

Fix those errors, and the browser should start showing your page correctly.

Hope that helps.

Comment: My code was clean in human's eye but not in browsers eye because of bad coding. I used UTF-8 with BOM but I had to use UTF-8 without BOM.